# Decode Json Swift 4 Codable Type Any

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Hey guys I have a problem with decoding. I have a Json which looks like this:

```
"data": [
            [
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                "",
                ""
            ],
            [
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                "",
                ""
            ],
            [
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                DoubleValue,
                "",
                ""
            ]
]
```

So my suggestion was to create a let data which contains a [[Any]] but this will not work with Codable and [[Double]] is not usable because if the value is empty the api send me the empty string and I get a typeMismatch error.

have someone a suggestion how to solve this problem?

my current Codable looks like

```
public struct JsonData: Codable {

var data: [[Double?]] = []

enum JsonDataCodingKey: String, CodingKey {

    case data
}

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: JsonDataCodingKey.self)

    var nestedContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .data)
    while !nestedContainer.isAtEnd {

        var innerContainer = try nestedContainer.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
        var dataSet: [Double?] = []
        while !innerContainer.isAtEnd {
            let value = try innerContainer.decodeIfPresent(Double.self)
            dataSet.append(value)
        }
        data.append(dataSet)
    }
}
```

}

But with this code I get the problem that typeMismatch if the empty string will come. -.- I tried to solve this now for hours but I didn't get the solution :(

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Remove the Optional then.

Comment: this will not fix my problem

Comment: What do you want the final data structure to look like? Should the first block have 5 values (ignoring "") or 7 values (replacing "" with some double value?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have is making an `enum` that can decode as either a `Double` or a `String` and decode an array of those.

Another option is to just catch the `typeMismatch` error and keep going:

```
var dataSet = [Double]()
while !innerContainer.isAtEnd {
    do {
        dataSet.append(try innerContainer.decode(Double.self))
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
        // Throw away the value by decoding something which doesn't actually decode.
        struct Empty : Codable {}
        let _ = try innerContainer.decode(Empty.self)
    }
}
```

This code throws away all non-`Double` values and gets rid of the `Optional`, but you can keep the `Optional` typing and insert `nil` instead of throwing away the values if you'd like.